# How to pass parameter from query to subquery?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

In MySQL workbench I can do something like that

```
SELECT 
    projects.ProjectName
    , @a:=projects.StartDate 
FROM
    projects
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*), projectID 
                 FROM eventTable 
                 WHERE eventTime > @a 
                 GROUP BY eventTime) AS tbl
    ON projects.ProjectID = tbl.projectID;
```

(my query is actually much longer, but this simple one can show my problem)

In C#, every parameter need to be predefined with `MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",...)`

How do I pass a parameter from the top query to the subquery?

Comment: a *parameter* will be available everywhere at once; however, can I check: can you not just refer to the *column* in the inner query? i.e. `where eventTime > projects.StartDate` ?

Comment: I found the solution at [link](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2009/05/mysqldatamysqlclientmysqlexception-parameter-id-must-be-defined.html). Need to add to the connection string: "Allow User Variables=True"

Comment: Marc, thanks for the answer.
No I cannot refer to the column of the outer query in the subquery.
The subquery is not "aware" of the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Personally with your query I am wondering if you are maybe over-complicating things. Having a sub-query can increase the processing requirements so it's often better to find alternative solutions.

As stated in the comment, you do not need to pass the item as a parameter to the sub-query as any joined table values can be used in a sub-query within linking. Using your example:

```
SELECT 
    projects.ProjectName
    , projects.StartDate 
FROM
    projects
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*), projectID 
                 FROM eventTable 
                 WHERE eventTime > projects.StartDate 
                 GROUP BY eventTime) AS tbl
    ON projects.ProjectID = tbl.projectID
```

I expect that you're probably going to be doing some form of additional work with this sub-query afterwards, maybe in a `WHERE` clause. In this instance I would suggest you probably end up also looking into options such as `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` which won't require you to run the sub query for each row.

Using your query, and assuming you want to know where a project have more than 10 events starting after the project starts:

```
SELECT 
    projects.ProjectName
    , projects.StartDate 
FROM
    projects
    -- Using a left join so you can have a count of 0
    LEFT JOIN eventTable ON eventTable.ProjectID = projects.ProjectID
WHERE
    eventTable.eventTime > projects.StartDate
GROUP BY
    projects.ProjectName
    , projects.StartDate 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 10
```

My answer is primarily conjecture, if you want to add more detail as to the actual problem being experienced I am happy to look into this again. But as previously stated, in your example you don't actually need to use a parameter.

---

**EDIT/ADDITION:**

The addition of the following information:

> What I need the outcome is a table (to display) of list of projects and how many events each one has, and when is the last one

and

> The event table has more then 10 millions records, while projects has 20

Makes me think that I think the inefficiencies of subqueries (which to my knowledge scan the whole table) and joining to a large table are about equivalent. MySql is normally quite good at optimising it's own queries; I understand that using functions such as [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) will often give pointers on how to improve indexing etc.

Here's my suggestions for the above comments:

**SUBQUERY:**

```
SELECT 
    projects.ProjectName
    , projects.StartDate 
FROM
    projects
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) totalEvents, MAX(eventTime) lastEventTime, projectID 
                 FROM eventTable 
                 WHERE eventTime > projects.StartDate 
                 GROUP BY eventTime) AS tbl
    ON projects.ProjectID = tbl.projectID
```

**JOIN:**

```
SELECT 
    projects.ProjectName
    , projects.StartDate 
    , COUNT(*) totalEvents
    , MAX(eventTime) lastEventTime
FROM
    projects
    -- Using a left join so you can have a count of 0
    LEFT JOIN eventTable ON eventTable.ProjectID = projects.ProjectID
WHERE
    eventTable.eventTime > projects.StartDate
GROUP BY
    projects.ProjectName
    , projects.StartDate
```

Any feedback on the performance of each in the comments would obviously be great for my learning too :-)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to remove the subquery.
What I need the outcome is a table (to display) of list of projects and how many events each one has, and when is the last one.
The event table has more then 10 millions records, while projects has 20, so I didn't want to join them.

Comment: The subquery got an error:
Unknown column 'projects.StartDate' in 'where clause'
The Join query has a problem that the "count" work on the join table and therefore returm same value to all projects.
I don't want to waste your time, since I manage to solve the problem with the: "Allow User Variables=True"
Thanks again.